# Resolution changing positions of objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, resolution

I've tried making a fixed width for the body tag but it seem to not work like it does to others... i'm obviously doing something wrong.
My question is : how do i make the screen not shrink and cause objects to be out of place
either by minimizing the screen or using a lower resolution?

I tried using percentages, as it is currently but it's not flawless.
 if you want to view the page yourself here it is

```
 <style type="text/css">

  div.register {
      border-style: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      right: 20.1%;
      left: 20.1%;
      top: 25%;
      bottom: 5%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      border-radius: 5px;
      font: 150% simple CLM;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #c1b7b7;
  }
  input.button {
      font:15px simple CLM;
      width:100px;
      border-style:none;
      border-radius:3px;
  }
  div.sleve {
      background-color: white;
      position: fixed ;
      right:20%;
      left: 20%;
      top: 1px;
      bottom: 1px;
      box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #c1b7b7;
      border-radius:10px
  }
  div.bar {
      position: absolute;
      right: 20%;
      left: 20%;
      top: 17.5%;
      background-color: #2D95B5;
      font: 100% simple CLM;
      color: white;
      height: 40px;
      border-top-width:1px;
      border-bottom-width:1px;
      border-left-width:0px;
      border-right-width:0px;
      border-style:solid;
      border-color:black;
  }
  td.barbutton {
      width:200px;
      height:35px;
      left:50px;
      right:50px;
      text-align:center;
  }
      td.barbutton:hover {
          background-color: #30A3C6;
      }
  div.register2 {
      position: fixed;
      height: 75%;
      width: 70%;
      left: 15%;
      top: 10%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      border-color: navajowhite;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px 1px #c1b7b7;
      border-radius: 10px;
      opacity: 0;
      font: 125% simple CLM;
  }
  div.register3 {
      position: fixed;
      height: 75%;
      width: 70%;
      left: 15%;
      top: 10%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      border-color: navajowhite;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px 1px #c1b7b7;
      border-radius: 10px;
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
      font: 125% simple CLM;
  }
  input.text {
      width: 150px;
      height:20px;
      border-style:none;
      border-radius:3px;
      font-size:60%;
      text-align:left          
  }
  input.password {
      width: 150px;
      height: 20px;
      border-style: none;
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-size: 60%;
      text-align:left
  }
      input.button:hover {
          background-color: #EBE7E7;
          border-color: white;
      }
</style>
```

```
 <div class="sleve"></div>
 <div class="bar">
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td class="barbutton" onclick="window.location='Main.aspx'">ראשי</td>
             <td class="barbutton">טקסט</td>
             <td class="barbutton">טקסט</td>
             <td class="barbutton">טקסט</td>
             <td class="barbutton">טקסט</td>
             <td class="barbutton" onclick="window.location='Register.aspx'">הירשם</td>


         </tr>

     </table>



 </div>




     <div class="register" id="register1" dir="ltr"  >
         <center style="font-size:150%; margin-top:5%;"><font face="simple clm">הרשמה לאתר</font></center>
         <form action="">
         <table dir="rtl" style="position:relative; margin-top:5%; margin-right:10%; font-size:100%" cellpadding="17.5%" cellspacing="15%;">
             <tr>
                 <td>שם משתמש</td> 
                 <td><input class="text" dir="ltr" id="ID" name="ID" /> <br /><p id="iderror" style="position:absolute; top:11%; color:red; font:65% arial; display:none">חייב להכיל בין 3 עד 16 תווים</p></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>סיסמא</td>
                 <td><input dir="ltr" class="password" type="password" id="PW" name="PW" /><br /><p id="pwerror" style="position:absolute; top:30.5%; color:red; font:65% arial; display:none">חייב להכיל בין 6 עד 24 תווים</p></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>אימייל</td>
                 <td><input class="text" dir="ltr" id="EMAIL" name="EMAIL" /><br /><p id="emailerror" style="position:absolute; top:50%; color:red; font:65% arial; display:none">חובה להכניס אימייל תקין</p></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>שנת לידה</td>
                 <td><input class="text" id="BDyear" maxlength="4" style="width:8%" />&nbsp/&nbsp<input class="text" id="BDmonth" maxlength="2" style="width:5%" />&nbsp/&nbsp<input class="text" id="BDday" maxlength="2" style="width:5%" /><br />
                     <p id="bderror" style="position:absolute; top:70%; color:red; font:65% arial; display:none"> תאריך לידה לא תקין</p>
                     <p id="bderroryoung" style="position:absolute; top:70%; color:red; font:65% arial; display:none"> חובה להיות מעל גיל 13</p>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td colspan="2"><center></center></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>

             </tr>

         </table>
             <input type="button" id="SEND" name="SEND" value="המשך" class="button" onclick="validate()" style="position:absolute; left:50%; bottom:25%" />
           <p style="position:absolute; left:45%; bottom:10%; font-size:medium" >כבר יש לך משתמש? &nbsp<a href="Login.aspx">התחבר</a></p>
         </form>




 </div>

 <div class="register2" id="register2" style="display:none">
     <center style="font-size:150%; margin-top:5%;"><font face="simple clm">עריכת פרופיל</font></center>
     <table style="position:absolute; bottom:30%; right:30%">
         <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
         </tr>



     </table>
  <form>
     <table dir="rtl" style="position:absolute; right:15%; bottom:15%" cellpadding="15%" cellspacing="20%">

         <tr>
             <td>שם מלא</td>
             <td><input class="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>מין</td>
             <td><input style="height:15px; width:30px" type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="זכר" />זכר <input type="radio" style="height: 15px; width: 30px" id="female" name="gender" />נקבה</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>עיסוקים\תחביבים</td>
             <td><input class="text" id="hobbies" name="hobbies" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>איזור בארץ</td>
             <td><input class="text" id="livingarea" name="livingarea" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>קצת על עצמך</td>
             <td><textarea style="width: 200%; height: 100px; border-style: none; border-radius: 3px; font-size: 80%; "></textarea></td>
         </tr>

     </table></form>

     <p style="position: fixed; left: 15.5%; top: 22.5%; width: 20%; font: 100% simple CLM;">תמונת פרופיל</p>
     <img  style="position: absolute; left: 17%; top: 25%; width: 12%; box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px #c1b7b7;" src="img/placeholder.png" />
     <input  class="button" type="button" value="העלה" style="position: fixed; left: 31.5%; top: 45.5%; width: 80px; font: 75% simple CLM;" />
     <input  class="button" type="button" value="קישור" style="position: fixed; left: 26.5%; top: 45.5%; width: 80px; font: 75% simple CLM;" />
     <p  style="position:absolute; right:20%; bottom:10%; font: small arial; color:red">*לא חובה למלא פרטים אלה</p>
     <input  class="button" type="button" style="position:absolute; width:200px; height:30px; right:40%; bottom:5%; font: large simple CLM" value="הירשם" onclick="done()" />
     <input class="button" type="button" style="position:absolute; width:200px; height:30px; right:5%; bottom:5%; font: large simple CLM" value="חזרה" onclick="backwards()" />

 </div>
 <div id="register3" class="register3" >
     <center style="font-size:150%; margin-top:5%;"><font face="simple clm">ההרשמה בוצעה בהצלחה</font></center>
     <center><p id="finishtext" style="margin-top:10%"></p></center>
     <input type="button" class="button" style="position:absolute; left:43%; bottom:20%; width:200px; height:30px" value="חזרה לעמוד הראשי" onclick="location = 'register.aspx'" />

 </div>
    </body
```

this does not include any of the javascript functions and will not do anything if you click. it's just an example of what happens - full hd users will see it perfectly and as you take down the resolution it starts to get out of place

Comment: In general, using `position:absolute` for website layout is not a good idea. It has it's uses but general layout is not one of them: http://learnlayout.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about preventing the `body` from going below a certain width, it seems you may want to look at `min-width`

E.g:

```
html,body{
  width:100%;
  min-width:980px;
}
```

[**More from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)

> The min-width CSS property is used to set the minimum width of a given
>   element. It prevents the used value of the width property from
>   becoming smaller than the value specified for min-width.
>
> The value of min-width overrides both max-width and width.

If you're thinking along the lines of scaling content based on viewport size, you should [look at `vh` or `vw` units.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

> Viewport-percentage lengths defined a length relatively to the size of
>   viewport, that is the visible portion of the document. Only
>   Gecko-based browser are updating the uw3e values dynamically, when the
>   size of the viewport is modified (by modifying the size of the window
>   on a desktop computer or by turning the device on a phone or a
>   tablet).

If you want the page to be reactive depending on size- most likely your best solution will be to use **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)** in order to help you specifically dictate how content should appear at certain sizes/resolutions.

> A media query consists of a media type and at least one expression
>   that limits the style sheets' scope by using media features, such as
>   width, height, and color. Media queries, added in CSS3, let the
>   presentation of content be tailored to a specific range of output
>   devices without having to change the content itself.

Comment: html,body{
  width:100%;
  min-width:980px;
} does not affect the website at all though i will take alook into the media queries. it's what i've mainly thinking of as a soltuon

Comment: Lets see if i understand. if i use the media queries to identify user resolution and then link it a style-sheet with all the sizes on it - which that will show on the user's screen organized? what format should i use if i set this up - percentages or pixels?